# Is there a function to that creates a custom block inside my gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, block, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm making a slider block and I want to create a slide block for each image I choose.

I already have a fully functioning slide block.
The question is, how can I create call the slide block from the slider block? I think there must be a way through the API and I found the function createBlock() but nothing is really working

```
const { createBlock } = wp.blocks;
//
// some code
//
<div id={ listId } className={ classes } key={ index }>
  {createBlock('illmatic6514/slide')}
</div>
```

I'm expecting a slide block to be created. (To make it simple I removed variables from the slide block and put in a static image)
I'm getting "Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"

Even if I call createBlock('core/paragraph') I get "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to define Slide as a component instead of a block:

```
function Slide(props) {
  return <div>{props.slideName}</div>;
}
```

Or as a class that extends Component:

```
const { Component } = wp.element
class Slide extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{ this.props.slideName }</div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then in your Slider block you would use that component:

```
edit(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Slide slideName="Slide 1" />
      <Slide slideName="Slide 2" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html